# How to Change Title Text Colour of NavigationController in iOS using Xamarin

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to change the Title text Colour of `NavigationController` in `iOS` using `Xamarin` but I am unable to change it.

Could someone please help me in achieving it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I tried in this way and it worked for me.

```
        var navigationBar = NavigationController.NavigationBar;
        navigationBar.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes() { TextColor = UIColor.White });
```

Sathish

Edit:

`UINavigationBar` no longer has the method `SetTitleTextAttributes`. Instead you must set the `TitleTextAttributes` property to a `UIStringAttributes` property like so:

```
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes() { ForegroundColor = UIColor.White };
```

Comment: I don't believe this works anymore. `UINavigationBar` doesn't have the `SetTitleTextAttributes` method and instead it is the property `TitleTextAttributes` which needs to be set to a `UIStringAttributes` object. See @megaKertz answer. `this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes() {
            ForegroundColor = UIColor.White
        };`

Answer (score 6):

This post is old but I think this is what you need:

```
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes() {
            ForegroundColor = UIColor.White
        };
```

worked for xamarin Unified API

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change it directly. Only through appearance or by using your own view as the title. Here's the solution for using appearance in Xamarin.iOS:

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes {
  TextColor = UIColor.Purple
});
```

Answer (score 1):

titleTextAttributes
Display attributes for the bar’s title text.

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *titleTextAttributes
```

Discussion
You can specify the font, text color, text shadow color, and text shadow offset for the title in the text attributes dictionary, using the text attribute keys described in NSString UIKit Additions Reference.